# reproducing caret confusionMatrix sensitivity and specificity (they seem to be swapped) and PPV (seems to be labled NPV)

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I'm having trouble with reproducing the sensitivity and specificity parameters from the `caret` confusion matrix values. (Apologies in advance that this is not reproducible, but I hope I show enough code to be clear; other than the `pROC` reference, it should be able to be reproduced by any (0,1) vectors of truth and prediction).

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity:

- sensitivity (aka recall aka TPR) = TP / (TP + FN)
- specificity (aka selectivity aka TNR) = TN / (TN + FP)
- precision (aka positive predictive value or PPV) = TP / (TP + FP)

My confusion matrix:

```
> cm = confusionMatrix(factor(y_pred),factor(y_test))
> cm$table
          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 8883  374
         1 1440 1640
```

from which I take

```
> TP=1640; FP=1440; FN=374; TN=8883
> cm$byClass
         Sensitivity          Specificity       Pos Pred Value       Neg Pred Value 
           0.8605057            0.8142999            0.9595981            0.5324675 
           Precision               Recall                   F1           Prevalence 
           0.9595981            0.8605057            0.9073544            0.8367512 
      Detection Rate Detection Prevalence    Balanced Accuracy 
           0.7200292            0.7503445            0.8374028 
> TP / (TP + FN)  #sensitivity aka Recall aka TPR
[1] 0.8142999
> TN / (TN + FP)  #Specificity 
[1] 0.8605057
> TP / (TP + FP)  #precision aka PPV
[1] 0.5324675
> TN / (TN + FN)  # NPV
[1] 0.9595981
```

It looks as as the data returned is mis-labeled - Specificity and Sensitivity have been swapped, and so have Pos Pred Value and Neg Pred Value.

Cross checking with `pROC`:

```
> best_thr = coords(pROC_obj,x='best',input='threshold',transpose=TRUE)
> best_thr
  threshold specificity sensitivity 
  0.2204595   0.8605057   0.8142999
```

seems to verify that the `confustionMatrix` Sensitivity and Specificity values have been swapped.

What's most concerning about this is that the F1 value, which I was going to retrieve, is way off when I try to verify it:

```
 > cm$byClass[7]
       F1 
0.9073544 
 > TP / (TP + (FP+FN)/2)   # F1
[1] 0.6438948
```

I'm using R version 3.5.3 with the (freshly installed) `pROC` and `caret` packages.
Am I doing something wrong with my calculations, or is it possible the `caret confusionMatrix` is actually returning the wrong values (particularly F1)? 
(I would presume I am more likely wrong, but the `pROC coords` agreed with me and disagrees with the `confusionMatrix`.)

Comment: I noticed this problem happens if your outcome is labelled as a word and the positive case's name is lower in the alphabet than the negative case (like case=positive and control=negative); caret automatically assigns the positive class as the first word to show up in the alphabet. Try ```cm = confusionMatrix(factor(y_pred),factor(y_test), positive=positive)``` or ```positive=whatever_name```

Comment: @PleaseHelp if you want to add this comment as an answer I will accept it! Thanks - James

Answer (score 1):

I had two values (0 and 1) in "y_pred" and "y_test".
I wanted to predict 1s.
For example:

```
y_pred = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0)
y_test = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0)
```

When I executed:

```
cm = confusionMatrix(factor(y_pred),factor(y_test), positive="1")
```

the output was correct.